# IRS 10% penalty on gains from an annuity

Tags: united-states, taxes, annuity, penalty

I consider myself a reasonably proficient investor but annuities are new to me.

For my short-term cash needs, I've been CD laddering.

As I look to invest for 2026 maturity (5 year), CDs are returning max 1% while "multi-year guaranteed annuities" (MYGA) are hovering around 3%.

The annuity bumpf compares MYGAs to CDs but the fineprint includes "The IRS issues a 10% penalty on gains withdrawn from a fixed annuity for account holders under age 59½.".

I'm 53.

An I correct in understanding that, at maturity, I can withdraw the original investment amount and pay income tax but with the extra 10% penalty on the gain?

By my math, I'd still be ahead:

- Annuity $$$+(1.03^5 less income tax + 10%)
- CD $$$+(1.01^5  less income tax)

Am I missing anything else?

Comment: All you need to know about annuities is that they are bad news, as are most "complex investment products".  They are simply better investments wrapped in a bunch of complexity and internal fees, which make sure the bank harvests most of the profit from those underlying investments instead of you.   A well-informed investor is surely aware of John Bogle's view, which is the most reliable investment on earth is avoiding a fee.  Heck, 10% is nearly the long term capital gains tax!  And you should be paying LTCG not standard income tax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take money out of your annuity before age 59½, you pay the penalty.  I don't know anything about MYGAs so I don't know anything about the applicability of the following:

From [Ameriprise](https://www.ameriprise.com/financial-goals-priorities/taxes/how-are-annuities-taxed/):

> Annuity withdrawals made before you reach age 59½ are typically subject to a 10% early withdrawal penalty tax. For early withdrawals from a qualified annuity, the entire distribution amount may be subject to the penalty. If you withdraw money early from a non-qualified annuity, typically only earnings and interest will be subject to the penalty.

(A non-qualified annuity is paid for with after-tax money)

I'd add that some insurance companies have a general cash account and you can leave the money in it for the additional time needed to reach age 59½.

Comment: Wow! This is even worse than I thought "the entire distribution amount". Though I would be using after-tax money, the "typically" concerns me. Thank you!

Comment: Bear in mind that I said that I don't know about applicability.  Find out whether the MYGA is or isn't qualified.

Comment: Yes, understood. Thank you. My contribution would definitely be after-tax so I assume the IRS can't tax me twice on the invested amount. But I'll certainly read up more on these.